# Securely transmit signed token (e.g., JWT) over insecure channel

Tags: key-exchange, transport-security, jwt

Apologies if this is already answered somewhere, but I could not find it.

I have a setup where a client has a JWT (RSA- or ECDSA-signed), and needs to prove that fact to the peer which issued the token in the first place, in a way that's safe against person-in-the-mittle attacks. The peers have no prior knowledge of each other (i.e., no trusted certificates etc.). I was wondering whether the following is an authentication scheme that works, or has any obvious flaws. To limit the scope, let us not get into all the issues with JWTs or improper use of cryptographic functions (duplicate IVs etc).

Let A be the peer with the JWT and B the peer that issued the JWT with key pair $\langle K_{pub}, K_{priv}\rangle$.

1. A sends nonce $n_A$ to B
2. B generates an ephemeral X25519 key pair $\langle E_{pub}, E_{priv}\rangle$ and responds with $sign(\langle K_{pub}, n_A, E_{pub}\rangle, K_{priv})$.
3. A verifies the JWT signature as well as the payload signature against $K_{pub}$.
4. A sends $enc(JWT, E_{pub})$ to B (or generates a symmetric session key, uses that to encrypt JWT, and encrypts the session key with $E_{pub}$).

The nonce $n_A$ ensures that the signature generated in B is specific to the current transaction and not replayed. After the verification in step 3, A knows that B is the holder of the private key used to issue the token in the first place. Encrypting with $E_{pub}$ ensures that an attacker M can not decrypt the encrypted token (and they cannot inject their own $E^M_{pub}$ because the transmitted $E_{pub}$ is signed with $K_{priv}$, which M has no knowledge of).

I realize that there are a lot of subtleties and am not expecting a "certified secure" answer, but it would be great if anyone could (a) point me to similar authentication schemes used in practice, and/or (b) point out any obvious flaws/weaknesses in the proposed scheme.

Many thanks!

Comment: When you say "no prior knowledge of each other", does it include $K_{pub}$?

Comment: Correct, $K_{pub}$ is not known by the client ahead of time, and taken from the message sent by B in 2. However, whatever $K_{pub}$ is sent needs to be able to validate the signature of the JWT kept by A. I'm not sure if the generation of a matching asymmetric key pair for a single (data, signature) pair is relatively easy, but since the JWT up until step 4 is kept fully private and not shared with anyone (encrypted or not), I don't think that this attack would be available to M anyway.

Comment: How do you know that $K_{pub}$ is not generated by a mitm, like all the rest of the data?

Comment: Because a $K_{pub}$ generated by M would fail the JWT signature validation in step 3. With no knowledge about the JWT (everything A has sent thus far is a nonce), it seems impossible to generate a $K_{pub}$ that can be used to validate the JWT signature.

Comment: I see now. So if you can verify $K_{pub}$ like that, can you also use it to encrypt JWT instead of $E_{pub}$?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be possible. However, I think an ephemeral key would be preferable, not only for PFS, but also to account for signature algorithms that can't simply be used for encryption (such as ECDSA)